# How to solve update form problem validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

In my Laravel 5.8, I want to update a medecin in my database.

I have a MedecinController and a method update with FormRequest.

When I make a mistake like put a required field empty, I have an error.

But when I make a modification in my complement field, nothing... No update, no error message.

My form contains 10 others fields not required.

Can you help me ?

MedecinController :

```
public function update(CreateUpdateMedecinRequest $request, $id)
{
    $medecin = Medecin::findOrFail($id);
    $medecin->m_complement = $request->input('complement');
    $medecin->save();

    return back();
}
```

CreateUpdateMedecinRequest :

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole([7,6]))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nom' => 'required',
        'adresse' => 'required',
        'cp' => 'required|max:5',
        'ville' => 'required',
        'telephone' => 'required',
        'specialite' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Routes :

```
Route::resource('medecins', 'Medecin\MedecinController', [
    'only' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'edit', 'update'],
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'viewMedecins',
        'create' => 'createMedecin',
        'store' => 'storeMedecin',
        'edit' => 'editMedecin',
        'update' => 'updateMedecin'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Could you check if you have your routes well defined either as a `POST` or `UPDATE`/`PATCH` method. One thing that might give you some info to troubleshoot your problem is adding a `dd($request->all())` in your update method

Comment: I update my post with Routes. For the EDIT I put an hidden input type method PUT or PATCH.

The dd($request->all()) doesn't work in my update method if I have no error. If I have errors, the Form Request take the lead and give me the errors for the field required

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you separate Create and Update form requests.

For example, make the following form requests: (`MedecinPostRequest` or `MedecinCreateRequest`) and (`MedecinPutRequest` or `MedecinUpdateRequest`)

This way you will have a more DRY code. Next, use created requests in your controller class as following:

`public function create(MedecinPostRequest $request, $id)`

`public function update(MedecinPutRequest $request, $id)`

By doing this, you will have more control over your incoming requests, you can authorize users if you have some specific role in future that one role can only create Medecin and other just to update Medecin or whatever future model with this pattern.

Now that you have 2 form requests, make sure that all fields are required in post request that needs to be required, and in the update, they are required only if present. Also in the update request if you need to ignore unique field validation you can do so with ease. (Example: name has to be unique but can be the same as the updated record.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I create two form requests.

But I don't understand why I have to make sure all fields are required in POST or PUT ? I have ten fields, 5 only are required, the others are possibly empty.

How I can treat that ?

Comment: For possibly empty fields just omit "required" rule in the rules array.

How I like to structure form requests is per request method.

`post` for creation. (in here I have all fields that cannot be null in the database required)
`put` for record replacement (this request has same rules as a `post` but I check that unique value are acceptable for the updated record.)
`patch` for partial record update (this request does not contain any 'require' condition, and fields are validated only when present by adding request rule `sometimes`

Comment: I try to add the optional field by putting nullable in my rules.
That still don't work... I don't understand...

Comment: Try with `sometimes` instead of `nullable`.